# How to properly encode UTF-8 in iOS using NSMutableURLRequest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, utf-8, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to send information to a login web service but certain characters are giving me trouble.

For example, if the password is something like `h+4hfP`, the web service rejects it because the plus sign ('+') is not properly encoded to `%2B`.

The web service uses UTF-8 encoding so I have been building an NSData object with this NSString method, `- (NSData *)dataUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;` choosing `NSUTF8StringEncoding` as the encoding.

This doesn't seem to be enough though.

The problem could also be with how I'm building an `NSMutableURLRequest`:

```
NSData *postData = [@"h+4hfP" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:contentLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

How can I ensure the encoding is done properly?

Comment: I was able to use the category [found here][1] to solve this issue.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18246169/869936

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
 [theRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: I ran into a similar problem. The critical important piece for me was the "charset=UTF-8" in the content-type field which was missing from OP.

Answer (score 0):

You could percent encode the string before representing it as NSData:

```
NSString *password = [@"h+4hfP" stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
NSData *postData = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution:
I was facing this problem. After some hours and search, I discovered this:
http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios

Solution:
1st: You must create  a method or class with content:

```
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding withString:(NSString *) str{
return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                           (CFStringRef)str,
                                                           NULL,
                                                           (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                                                           CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding)));
```

}

2nd: Use:

```
NSString *stringToSend = [self urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding withString:stringToBeVerifyed];
```

Then

```
NSData *postData = [stringToSend dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[...]
```